# VB DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged Event Not Firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a `dropdownlist` that, when a specific item is selected, needs to set another `dropdownlist.visible = true`. Unfortunately, I cannot get the `dropdownlist` (or any other `dropdownlist` on my entire site) to fire its `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Details:

- This is a site that was created by my predecessor and I do not have the time to rebuild it or even upgrade it so, I really need to simply add this one feature to complete my task.
- The site is written in Visual Studio .NET 2003.
- Currently, no matter what I try, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event never fires.

I have tried the following things:

1. Set `AutoPostBack="true"`
2. Set `AutoEventWireup="true"`
3. Set `EnableViewState="true"`
4. Add `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCLSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged"` to the asp:dropdownlist object, which gives me the following error:

   > Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'ddlCLSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.reports_aspx'.

   This error has led me down the path of checking any differences in the Inherits and Class name, but the only difference I found is that the class is named `reports` and the Inherits is `ProviderLicense.reports`. Of course, when I change them to match identically, that throws a completely different error.
5. Change the `ddlCLSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged` Sub from `Private` to `Protected`, and then even to `Public` just for good measure.
6. Remove the `Handles ddlCLSortOptions.SelectedIndexChanged` and add the `AddHandler` option

I'm sure there's even more that I've tried, but I can't think of anything else.

Here is my code:

**reports.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="reports.aspx.vb" Inherits="ProviderLicense.reports"%>
...
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCLSortOptions" style="POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 365px; Z-INDEX: 140; TOP: 315px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Provider" Selected="True">Provider</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="RecDate">Received Date</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="EntDate">Entered Date</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DateComp">Date Completed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LicType">License Type</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Investigator">Investigator</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Worker">Worker</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Disposition">Disposition</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

**reports.aspx.vb**

```
Public Class reports
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected WithEvents ddlCLSortOptions As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
...
Private Sub ddlCLSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCLSortOptions.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label2.Text = "IT WORKED!"    'Just to see if the event fires

    If ddlCLSortOptions.SelectedValue = "Disposition" Then
        lblDisposition.Visible = True
        ddlDisposition.Visible = True
    Else
        lblDisposition.Visible = False
        ddlDisposition.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope it's something simple that I've just missed, but I'm open to trying just about anything now.

Comment: change the VS tag to an ASP tag to attract the appropriate eyes

Comment: thanks just changed it

Comment: Setting the AutoPostBack = True makes it work for me. Try it in a new project to test it. If it still will not work in your current project, delete and recreate the control.

Comment: It seems that for nearly everyone online, setting AutoPostBack=True works; unfortunately, that does not work for me. 

Additionally, I have deleted and recreated the control, both manually and automatically by double clicking the dropdownlist. 

Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

set `AutoEventWireUp="false"` in `reports.aspx`

set the `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCLSortOptions"` in the DropDownList tag in `reports.aspx`

change `Private Sub` to `Protected Sub` on the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in `reports.aspx.vb`

Comment: I knew I'd set each of those at one time, but wasn't sure if I'd specifically had them all set at the same time so, I just did that.
However, I received the following error:
**BC30408: Method 'Protected Dim WithEvents ddlCLSortOptions As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.**

I realized you probably meant it to be `ddlClSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged` but I now receive this error:
**BC30456: 'ddlClSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.reports_aspx'.**

Comment: if you pasted in that second error message, i would say your dropdown ID is wrong as they are case sensitive. ill have a look at the first one in a bit

Comment: I appreciate you noticing the lowercase 'L'. Unfortunately, that wasn't the problem. I still get the same error when I capitalize it: **BC30456: 'ddlCLSortOptions_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.reports_aspx'.**